# Passing unions of POD types between binary modules

Tags: c++, unions, abi

I'm implementing a shared library, and its logic implies using variant like types.
Of course I'm pretty aware that `std::variant`/`boost::variant` would be a better choice but, obviously, it's not an option when dealing with cross-module stuff.

And so, my main concern is whether it's safe to pass `union`s of POD types around between binary modules. Considering the modules are being compiled within the same platform (but compile options might differ from one module to another).

(As far as I know, it's generally safe to pass POD `struct`s, but may be there are some tricky issues related to `union`s)

So I'll appreciate any enlightenment on this point.

I've been trying to find some information about this, but haven't really succeeded. So, if my question duplicates an existing one, please just let me know.

Comment: @SupportUkraine, C++

Comment: Well, I thought if a structure is trivially copiable, it could be simply placed in registers regardless of compiler-specific ABI-defined behaviour. Isn't it true?

Comment: Alright, I see, thank you for clarifying this point. In this case, I'm thinking of passing a struct/union by const reference and (conventionally) disallowing the user to copy it, but instead accessing its fields (which are of fundamental types) and copying them if needed. What do you think of this?

Answer (score 0):

> And so, my main concern is whether it's safe to pass unions of POD types around between binary modules.

Yes, the size, layout and alignment of POD types will be consistent on a system.

> it's not an option when dealing with cross-module stuff.

Are you so sure?

Although the C and C++ standards do not specify an ABI, C++ compilers such as gcc and clang follow the Itanium ABI. If you use one of these compilers with the same compiler version (including the standard library version), even with different flags, the ABI should stay the same.

Comment: Sounds really cool, thank you! But since the project I'm currently working on is supposed to be compiled with various compilers and for different platforms (linux/windows/arm), I'm afraid it's not an option either.
But I'll certainly keep it in my mind for future projects!
By the way, is there some general or compiler-specific documentation describing ABI-related behaviour, so that I could rely on it in the future?